# Eraser/rubber for Android Canvas

Tags: android, canvas, save

Can any one tell me how to erase the color done on a canvas..i.e., I hv a colorful image on canvas that has been made B/W by drawing white color all over the canvas now it appeared to be a **sketched** image only which can be painted similarly as  other B/W image. Now the question is that My application has one option to fill the image with its original color with stroke of mouse(finger) only, According to me if i can erase the white color(or any of its color done above the original image) then i 'll achieve the required option..
   Any help...
Please suggest me any other way to achieve this also, if there is.....

Thanks,,,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be possible by creating a **photo-shop functionality named Masking**(or alpha masking or image masking) in android using porterduff and xfermode.

Comment: is there any example or code how to implement it ? or how to code it ?